# filter vs get performance in Django ORM, when there's only 1 object available for retrieval

Tags: sql, django, performance, django-orm

I have a Django application.
Solely in terms of **ORM/query/DB performance**, are the following ways of retrieving an object equivalent (i.e. in a situation where there was just a single `Car` object for `owner_id = pk` in the table currently):

```
Car.objects.get(owner_id=pk)

Car.objects.filter(owner_id=pk).latest('id')
```

`owner` is a foreign key relationship, hence is a DB index. Are the SQL queries produced equivalent (or the same)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using the Foreign key, `get()` and `filter()` will give the same performance.

How you see `get()`

`objs = Car.objects.get(owner_id=pk)`

How `get()` is actually implemented by Django

```
objs = Car.objects.filter(owner_id=pk)
   if len(objs) == 1:
      obj = objs[0]
   else if len(objs) > 1:
      # Multiple objects returned
   else: 
      # we have no object!  do something
      pass
```

For your case, I would recommend using `get()` because

1. you can be sure that only one element is returned
2. it is designed for this purpose

Answer (score 2):

They are not equivalent because `.get()` will return a [`DoesNotExist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.DoesNotExist) exception if nothing is found, while `.filter()` returns an empty queryset.

As for performance, I'd first make sure the field I am filtering by has an index in the DB.

Which is by default in Django for a [`ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)

> A database index is automatically created on the ForeignKey

Comment: Talk more about performance, which is my focus here. Indeed `owner` is a foreignkey in my table. To me, these statements look equivalent performance wise. What considerations am I missing?

Comment: @HassanBaig I bet that if you try to actually **profile** your code you'll see that the difference between the two statements is insignificant. So, given that no performance issues arise I'd go with the more clear statement for the task: `get` since you *known* that there will always be at most one result.

Comment: @Bakuriu: Okay, please add your opinion as a formal answer then, since that more directly attempts to answer my question than bakkal's reply.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, there is a performance difference.

There is an actual performance difference between `queryset.get(pk="somekey")` and `queryset.filter(pk="somekey").first()` even for filter so specific that it only matches one row.

I've observed this performance difference in tables containing dozens of millions rows.

The difference is that when you take `queryset.first()` element from queryset, the queryset is ordered_by *by default* by `pk` or by explicit `queryset.order_by('some_field')` or less explicit default ordering on model `class Meta`.

**Using `queryset.get()` doesn't order the queryset which can result in much better performance because ordering huge queryset can take some time.**

So using `queryset.filter(...).first()` for one element is generally less performant.